# Aura doesn't support paragraph in text

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

Does anyone know how to fix this one?

In Aura component (Apex - Salesforce) in .cmp, I have these lines of code:

```
<lightning:formattedRichText value="{!message.value__c}" />
```

The problem is if that message contains paragraph, that paragraph will not be shown...

So, for example, instead of showing

```
test test


test test
```

it shows

```
test test test test
```

Comment: Please avoid adding completely irrelevant tags. Apex is a language used for back end programming in Salesforce. Visualforce is a completely different UI technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML's default `white-space` property is set to `normal`, which is where multiple whitespace are collapsed into a single space. If you want multiple lines, you must either wrap the paragraphs into `p` elements or replace `\n` with `<br />`.

Comment: Can you, please, show me how to "replace `\n` with `<br />`" in my example `<lightning:formattedRichText value="{!message.value}" />`? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mhdev You would use String.replaceAll in your controller, such as `message.value = message.value.replaceAll(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/mg,'<br/>')`. You may also need to copy your object(s). You didn't include your JS, so I can't provide more specific guidance.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, `value` is actually FIELD from object so I updated my question ( changed the line of code `<lightning:formattedRichText value="{!message.value__c}" />`), so is there any option to "replace `\n` with `<br />`" in field?

Comment: @mhdev You still need to fix it in the controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works.